# Free webservice with database

Tags: android, web, webserver

is there any free web service which also provide a database? 
I am thinking for an application which hits a free web service and fetch and save some data.
Is there any kind of free web services to save my data and retrieve data when ever required from android. I visited Google cloud storage and API, but it doesn't look heavy for integration.
Can any one suggest me some easiest things?

Comment: You can use the [FireBase](https://www.firebase.com/) or [Parse](https://parse.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :
[a Parse](https://parse.com/)
[a programmableweb](http://www.programmableweb.com/)
or 
[a cloud-endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-endpoints/)

Answer (score 0):

Try Parse: https://parse.com/. I wrote a tutorial on how to get started with a simple app here: http://www.michaelevans.org/blog/2013/08/14/tutorial-building-an-android-to-do-list-app-using-parse/

Comment: Its really great, i tried it. But i dint get that is it really free upto a limit?

Comment: I tried the link You mentioned for android and it works fine. I am wondering if there is any tutorial for desktop windows client also, if it is please post the link